# Como editar o theme.xml no Titanium?

Tags: javascript, android, actionbar

Preciso retirar a actionBar do meu projeto e o melhor meio que encontrei foi editar o theme.xml. Porém, quando eu o edito, não consigo salva-lo e logo, minha actionBar continua ativa.
Tentei colocar a linha de código (abaixo) mas quando emulado, minhas janelas não carregam. Tentei escrever no começo e no final do projeto, sem sucesso.
$.index.activity.actionBar.hide();

Answer (score 0):

Após editar o theme.xml, é necessário referenciar ele no tiapp.xml, dentro da tag manifest, exemplo:

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
       <application android:theme="@style/nomeDoTema"/>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

Porém, nas últimas versões do Titanium (a partir da 4.2.0), você pode retirar a ActionBar de uma Window utilizando a propriedade "theme":

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({theme: "Theme.AppCompat.NoTitleBar"});
```

A documentação completa você encontra aqui: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Themes-section-34636181_AndroidThemes-TitaniumThemes